# How to rearrange a list of word in order to have a numberof words by line

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to accomplish a task using bash.

Let say I have

```
"a":1,
"y":1,
"a":1,
"y":1,
"à":1,
```

And I would like to have :

```
"a":1,"y":1,
"a":1,"y":1,
"à":1,
```

Which I translate to at most 2 elements per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'chomp if $. % 2' -- file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `$.` contains the current line number
- `%` is the module operator, therefore `$. % 2` returns true on odd lines
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the final newline

Pure bash solution:

```
i=0
while read line ; do
    printf %s "$line"
    ((i=\!i)) || printf '\n'
done < file
```

The variable `$i` toggles between 0 and 1, the newline is printed only for even lines.

Comment: @dstromberg: Right tool for the job etc. Pure bash solution added.

Answer (score 1):

Just paste file twice with no separator:

```
paste -d '' - - < input_file.txt
```